# How to convert a string to json object in c#

Tags: c#

I tried to convert my string to json object,but i got an error json string.

My code

```
public class mystring
{
    public string str { get; set; }
}

mystring myst = new mystring
{
    str = "Login successfully"
};

var javaScriptSerializer = new
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string jsonString = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(myst);
return jsonString;
```

But i got resuilt like this `"{\"str\":\"Login successfully\"}"`. Why this happened,Any idea?help me to get out of this issue..

Comment: because that is an json object not an error!

Comment: @WaqarAhmed:no,thats not a json string,i just check with json validator

Comment: @hakkeem Argue much? He's correct. Now if you want to talk JSON to JSON versus .NET JSON to JSON you have a different story.

Comment: How did you get that string? Did you see it in the debugger? Because if you did, the debugger value inspector will add the backslashes in front of quotes, in reality your string contains just this: `{"str":"Login successfully"}`.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the library `Json.Net` (Newtonsoft Json) in NuGet.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Answer (score 0):

All is right, this is valid Json String.

Validator fail, because when you copied this value from VisualStudio it shows character escaping too. (backslashes) e.g. (\")

You can Learn more about [Escape Sequences here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

In Reality your string contain `{"str":"Login successfully"}`. 
You can check it, it is valid JSON.

Comment: :ok,fine,i know this {"str":"Login successfully"} is a valid json,so i want to remove backslashes and double quotes from my string.

Answer (score 0):

`"{\"str\":\"Login successfully\"}"` is a valid ***string containing a json***. Just as a proof:

- Open Chrome
- press ctrl+shift+j
- go to console tab
- write this: `var obj = JSON.parse("{\"str\":\"Login successfully\"}")`
- press enter
- type `obj.str` to see the result which is "Login successfully"

Its' just that when you hover over the variable in debug mode, it shows like this.

Comment: No, that is a valid *string* containing json.

Comment: Updated, looks good?