# Unable to deserialize json string C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am sending json data from my server using GCM client to Android. Below is my code:

Server:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dataDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dataDict.Add("Text", Convert.ToString(dr["Message"]));
dataDict.Add("Type", Convert.ToString(dr["Type"]));

GcmJsonData jsonData = new GcmJsonData();
jsonData.alert = dataDict;
jsonData.sound = "sound.caf";
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(jsonData);
try
{
    //GcmNotification n = new GcmNotification();
    _push.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId("APA91bFoQBrmsBeoXSdU4-UdO30Wn")
        .WithJson(json));
}
```

Android:

```
string msgFromServer = "";
if (intent != null || intent.Extras != null)
{
    msgFromServer = intent.GetStringExtra("alert");
    string t = intent.GetStringExtra("Name");
}

msgFromServer = msgFromServer.Replace(@"\""", @"""");
Data d = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(msgFromServer);
```

msgFromServer is received as below:

```
"{\"Type\":\"GeneralAlert\",\"Text\":\"ga a\"}"
```

Hence I am unable to deserialize it.

How to fix it

Comment: I've not used GCM. What does `WithJson` do? Looks like you are double-serializing the object. Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101519/how-to-remove-backslashes-and-double-quotes-in-json-string

Comment: @Arghya C , WithJson is like user formatted json data to like payload to Android device. I am not serializing twice, I am sending dictionary object as notification msg to Android device

Comment: Tell me some way to deserialize above string format?

Comment: Then this code should work fine, what is the structure of your `Data` class?

Comment: When you say "I am unable to deserialize it", have you got an error message ? can you share it ?
Can you also put you Data Class ?

Also, maybe try to to create a Class instead of a dictionary (not sure it will change something, but give it a try).